# Can't add a folder with Python Google Drive API. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, directory, mime-types

I am trying to add a sub directory in my Google Drive folders but can't seem to get it right. The answers on StackOverflow have not helped me; I am doing exactly what is listed on the Google API page, but I am not getting the correct result. Here is the related code:

```
def create_course_folder(course):
    body = {
        'title': course,
        'mimetype': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': [{
            'id': folderIDs[get_parent_name_from_course(course)]
        }]
    }

    drive_service.files().insert(body=body).execute()
```

The code is mostly functional; I am able to add a new "folder" to the correct parent folder. However, the "folder" isn't a folder at all, it's a binary file. I tried adding another file to this "folder" thinking it was just a glitch, but I get an error stating that I am trying to add a file to a non-folder object. Has anyone else had this issue? I wonder if the mimetype for Google Drive folders has changed since I'm following the directions from their API site almost exactly.

Comment: Try changing the parameter 'mimetype'  to 'mimeType'  and see if that works for you.

Comment: Oh. My. God.
You're a damn life saver, I probably wouldn't have caught that.